# Как правильно настроить 301 редирект, если каталог или раздел находится в середине URL?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, redirect

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите как сделать 301 редирект в таком случае: с

```
site.com/OLD_category_name/item/page.html
```

на

```
site.com/NEW_category_name/item/page.html
```

Т.е. на сайте изменились названия категорий (все), а конечные страницы генерируются через категорию. Для страниц с самими категориями мы редирект настроили:

```
Redirect 301 /OLD_category_name.html http://site.com/NEW_category_name.html
```

А вот как настроить редирект для страниц со статьями?

Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^OLD_category_name/(.*) http://www.example.com/NEW_category_name/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.

Comment: Вопрос возник по ходу. В варианте, который вы дали выше это будет как 301 редирект работать или просто обычная переадресация?

Comment: Как 301 редирект - перемещен постоянно, то есть для поисковиков все ОК, они пропишут, что индексированный URL изменился.

Comment: Ок, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Решили проделать аналогичную операцию с сайтом, который работает через https и наткнулись на ошибку сервера. Редирект делали вот так:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^OLD_category_name/(.*) http://example.com/NEW_category_name/$1 [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 /OLD_category_name.html http://example.com/NEW_category_name.html`

Comment: В начале файла .htaccess нагорожена вот такая конструкция (из-за того, что при других настройках сайт через https работать не хочет):

В начале файла .htaccess вот такая запись:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} OFF
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: #First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here www.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Потом везде надо ставить https

Comment: Не туда написал комментарий) Получился ответ, вместо комментария.

Answer (score 0):

Ситуация такая.

С предложенным вами вариантом:

```
# First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here www.) 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

# Now, rewrite to HTTPS: 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} OFF 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

работае только главная. Т.е. при попытке перейти на страницу категории

```
http://example.com/NEW_category_name.html
```

пишет ошибку.

Заработало с вот таким вариантом:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Работает нормально редирект с "www" на без "www". Редирект со старых категорий на новые тоже работает нормально. Т.е. вот этот:

```
Redirect 301 /OLD_category_name.html http://example.com/NEW_category_name.html
```

Но не работает вот это правило:

```
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^OLD_category_name/(.*) http://example.com/NEW_category_name/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Т.е. не работает то, с чего собственно вопрос и начинался...